# Incomplete Permission Set Metadata

Tags: metadata

I am retrieving permission sets using VS Code, but they are incomplete, as they are missing many field permissions.
This is weird as the objects are included in the package.xml.
Anyone has an idea of what I may be missing?
A few days back it was retrieving correctly...